# Can I output results of a MySQL query to a Excel file via Putty?

Tags: linux, ssh, mysql, putty

I'm on a local windows machine. The MySQL DB is on a CentOS machine elsewhere on the same local network. I want to output the results of the query that I'm typing directly into Putty into an Excel (or csv) file elsewhere on the local network. How would I do this?

I tried something like

```
mysql> select * from table > \\server\my_documents\output.csv
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're starting a mysql interactive session.  Instead, you'll want to [execute the SQL from a text file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html), i.e.

```
mysql database_name < input.script.sql > output.file
```

You'll want to ensure that your SELECT statement outputs something usable, so something like what's mentioned in [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format).  Note that that answer already has the outfile specified, so you wouldn't need the redirect as shown above . . .

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```